# How to do Forward fill in Pyspark on multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, time-series

I want to do the forwad fill in Pyspark on multiple columns.
and if the start value of column is "NaN" then replace that with 0.
Below is my DF looks like.

| start_timestamp | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-02 08:51:50 | 2 | null | null | null |
| 2020-11-02 09:14:29 | null | null | null | 40 |
| 2020-11-02 09:18:32 | null | 4 | 2 | null |
| 2020-11-02 09:32:42 | 4 | null | null | null |
| 2020-11-03 13:06:03 | null | null | null | 20 |
| 2020-11-03 13:10:01 | 6 | null | 4 | null |
| 2020-11-03 13:54:38 | null | 5 | null | null |
| 2020-11-03 14:46:25 | null | null | null | null |
| 2020-11-03 14:57:31 | 7 | null | null | 10 |
| 2020-11-03 15:07:07 | 8 | 7 | null | null |

Expected DF would be:

| start_timestamp | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-02 08:51:50 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-11-02 09:14:29 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 40 |
| 2020-11-02 09:18:32 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 40 |
| 2020-11-02 09:32:42 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 40 |
| 2020-11-03 13:06:03 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 20 |
| 2020-11-03 13:10:01 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 20 |
| 2020-11-03 13:54:38 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 20 |
| 2020-11-03 14:46:25 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 20 |
| 2020-11-03 14:57:31 | 7 | 5 | 4 | 10 |
| 2020-11-03 15:07:07 | 8 | 7 | 4 | 10 |

Below is the code i tried which i got on stackoverflow:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import last,first
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max as max_, min as min_
import sys

def stringReplaceFunc(x, y):
    return F.when(x != y, x).otherwise(F.lit(None)) # replace with NULL

def forwardFillImputer(df, cols=[], partitioner="start_timestamp", value="null"): 
      for i in cols:
        window = Window\
        .partitionBy(F.month(partitioner))\
        .orderBy(partitioner)\
        .rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)
        df= df\
        .withColumn(i, stringReplaceFunc(F.col(i), value))
        fill = F.last(df[i], ignorenulls=True).over(window)
        df= df.withColumn(i,  fill)
        return df

df= forwardFillImputer(df, cols=[i for i in df.columns])
```

code is not functioning, Please let me know what mistake i am doing. Please let me know if there is any alternative solution. Thanks.

Comment: @thePurplePython Hi found your solution, Could you help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code, you should not partition your window by month, and using `rowsBetween` is useless. You should only have an ordered window per `start_timestamp`

Moreover, you're not managing the case when there is no last value. You can manage it using `coalesce` with literal value `'0'`

Thus your code can be rewritten as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

def forwardFillImputer(df, cols=[], partitioner='start_timestamp', value='null'):
    for c in cols:
        df = df.withColumn(c, F.when(F.col(c) != value, F.col(c)))
        df = df.withColumn(c, F.coalesce(F.col(c), F.last(c, True).over(Window.orderBy(partitioner)), F.lit('0')))
    return df

df = forwardFillImputer(df, df.columns)
```

with the following dataframe as `df`:

```
+-------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|start_timestamp    |Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|
+-------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|2020-11-02 08:51:50|2      |null   |null   |null   |
|2020-11-02 09:14:29|null   |null   |null   |40     |
|2020-11-02 09:18:32|null   |4      |2      |null   |
|2020-11-02 09:32:42|4      |null   |null   |null   |
|2020-11-03 13:06:03|null   |null   |null   |20     |
|2020-11-03 13:10:01|6      |null   |4      |null   |
|2020-11-03 13:54:38|null   |5      |null   |null   |
|2020-11-03 14:46:25|null   |null   |null   |null   |
|2020-11-03 14:57:31|7      |null   |null   |10     |
|2020-11-03 15:07:07|8      |7      |null   |null   |
+-------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

You get the following output:

```
+-------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|start_timestamp    |Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|
+-------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|2020-11-02 08:51:50|2      |0      |0      |0      |
|2020-11-02 09:14:29|2      |0      |0      |40     |
|2020-11-02 09:18:32|2      |4      |2      |40     |
|2020-11-02 09:32:42|4      |4      |2      |40     |
|2020-11-03 13:06:03|4      |4      |2      |20     |
|2020-11-03 13:10:01|6      |4      |4      |20     |
|2020-11-03 13:54:38|6      |5      |4      |20     |
|2020-11-03 14:46:25|6      |5      |4      |20     |
|2020-11-03 14:57:31|7      |5      |4      |10     |
|2020-11-03 15:07:07|8      |7      |4      |10     |
+-------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks, code worked, i made little change: 
 `def forwardFillImputer(data, cols=[], partitioner='resampled_start_timestamp', value='null'):
    for c in cols:
        data = data.withColumn(c, F.when(F.col(c).isNotNull(), F.col(c)))
        data = data.withColumn(c, F.coalesce(F.col(c), F.last(c, True).over(Window.orderBy(partitioner)), F.lit('0')))
    return data   

data = forwardFillImputer(data, data.columns)`